# Multiple word searching with Ruby, and MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby, search, activerecord

I'm trying to accomplish a multiple word searching in a quotes database using Ruby, ActiveRecord, and MySQL. The way I did is shown bellow, and it is working, but I would like to know if there a better way to do.

```
# receives a string, splits it in a array of words, create the 'conditions'
# query, and send it to ActiveRecord
def search
    query = params[:query].strip.split if params[:query]
    like = "quote LIKE "
    conditions = ""
    query.each do |word|
        conditions += (like + "'%#{word}%'")
        conditions += " AND " unless query.last == word
    end
    @quotes = Quote.all(:conditions => conditions)
end
```

I would like to know if there is better way to compose this 'conditions' string. I also tried it using string interpolation, e.g., using the * operator, but ended up needing more string processing. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, I strongly encourage you to move Model's logic into Models. Instead of creating the search logic into the Controller, create a #search method into your Quote mode.

```
class Quote
  def self.search(query)
    ...
  end
end
```

and your controller becomes

```
# receives a string, splits it in a array of words, create the 'conditions'
# query, and send it to ActiveRecord
def search
  @quotes = Quote.search(params[:query])
end
```

Now, back to the original problem. Your existing search logic does a very bad mistake: it directly interpolates value opening your code to SQL injection. Assuming you use Rails 3 you can take advantage of the new #where syntax.

```
class Quote
  def self.search(query)
    words = query.to_s.strip.split
    words.inject(scoped) do |combined_scope, word|
      combined_scope.where("quote LIKE ?", "%#{word}%")
    end
  end
end
```

It's a little bit of advanced topic. I you want to understand what the `combined_scope` + `inject` does, I recommend you to read the article [The Skinny on Scopes](http://edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2010/02/23/the-skinny-on-scopes-formerly-named-scope/).

Comment: Would be nice if you demonstrated mysql's full text searching in the examples

Comment: I'd recommend `to_s.downcase.strip.split.uniq` to fold to lower-case and remove duplicate words.

Comment: I'm using Rails 2.3.5, but anyway, the answer helped a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Rails 5 CHANGE: replace 'scoped' with 'all'. Been using this helpful answer for years.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL fulltext search not working, so best way to do this:

```
class Quote
  def self.search_by_quote(query)
    words = query.to_s.strip.split
    words.map! { |word| "quote LIKE '%#{word}%'" }
    sql = words.join(" AND ")
    self.where(sql)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The better way to do it would be to implement full text searching. You can do this in [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) but I would highly recommend [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). There are many resources [online](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=solr+rails) for implementing Solr within rails but I would recommend [Sunspot](http://outoftime.github.com/sunspot/) as an entrance point.

Comment: Solr is indeed a good choice, but is a quite complex library. There are cases where you don't actually need to add a Solr dependency and it is perfectly fine to try such kind of query against MySQL. I believe in this case the user can highly benefit from refactoring his code without necessary taking the step to try Solr.

Answer (score 0):

Create a FULLTEXT index in MySQL. With that, you can leave string processing to MySQL.

Example : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html