# Multi keyword search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I currently have a basic search that will allow me to type in a word and it will return back all records that are like that search. It is as followed:

application.html.erb

```
        <%= form_tag games_path, :method => 'get' do %>
            <%= hidden_field_tag :direction, params[:direction] %>
            <%= hidden_field_tag :sort, params[:sort] %>
            <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
        <%= submit_tag t('.searchb'), :game_name => nil %>
        <% end %>
```

controller and Model

```
        @games = Game.search(params[:search])

  def self.search(search)
     search = search.to_s.strip.split
     search.inject(scoped) do |combined_scope, search|
     combined_scope.where(['game_name LIKE ? OR genre LIKE ? OR console LIKE ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%"])
    end
  end
```

What I now wish to do though is the ability to enter multiple words in to the search bar and have it return all related records to those words rather than any record that has them all.

e.g. If I type fighting, action

I want it to return all fighting games and all action games.

How would I go about implementing this?
Model:

EDIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a fulltext search engine like Sphinx for this! There is a gem called `thinking-sphinx` wich offers an interface between ruby and the Sphinx server! The only downside is that you need to update the database periodly. It doesnt support live updates.

Comment: I was hoping for an option without using gems :/ I find it better to write code because it allows me to understand rails a lot better? I have updated the above with my model section (attached under the controller line) If I type one word that is fine but if I type two it tries to find a record that has the two words in rather than all records that have either.

Comment: Of cause you could implement your own fulltext search using MySQL Functions http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html but thats not the ruby way. Using gems isnt bad if you know what the gem does. Sphinx is a filltext search deamon and thinking sphinx is an interrface to use this daemon. You can read much about both of them. I dont see any sense in writing yur own search mechanism!

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the key words, loop them and create queries to achieve this. You can use inject to make it easy. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275876/multiple-word-searching-with-ruby-and-mysql) might help.

Comment: Hey I have showed about what I have in my model now (the top line is from the controller) I have done that and if for example I type 'border' it will return the associated games but if I type 'border good' (two game names) then it returns no records. ANy idea?