# Retrieving data matching with hash as column name - Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have personal_details table which having id, personal_detail_info column names. In personal_detail_info as text data type and saved as JSON data format.

e.g., **"{\"name\":\"XXXX\",\"email_id\":\"xyz@gmail.com\",\"phone_no\":\"12345678\",\"alternative_no\":\"25638780\"}"**

I have nearly 100 records in personal_details table. Need to fetch data from personal_details table whose name is xxx in Rails 4.2 Active Record Querying. How can i match with name? Could you please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275876/multiple-word-searching-with-ruby-and-mysql

Comment: Please provide what you have done so others can help debug your code rather than write your code for you.

Comment: let's assume, We have employee table with the following columns name, age, phone_number and depart. Now, i have to fetch data from employee table who belongs to HR department means that, i can write the below query.
employees = Employee.where('department = ?', "HR");
The same employee details we saved as JSON format with one column named as emp_personal_info. In this case, How can i write Rails Query